# how to append iterated array with associated data inside appended div

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, append

I am attempting to add data to the DOM based on an object. Within the object is an array for 'tags'. When appending a new div to the DOM with the data from the object, the tags will not render correctly when I loop through them. They don't correspond with the object data they are associated with.

I am not sure how to get them to display correctly. Any ideas would help, thank you

```
var houses = {


"house": [{
    "source": "images/background.jpg",
    "gallery": ["images/house-name-1.jpg", "images/house-name-2.jpg", "images/house-name-3.jpg"],
    "short_desc": "3 BR, 2 Bath, Bellville, NJ",
    "long_desc": "Great 2 family in a prime location. Close to public transportation, schools, and shopping. This property is subject to 3rd party approval, Town CO and permits to be paid by the buyer.",
    "address": "268 Washington Ave Belleville, NJ 07109",
    "sq_ft": "3,456 sqft",
    "price": "262,000",
    "tags": ["For Purchase", "Multi-family", "Duplex", "House", "3 Bed", "2 Bath"]
  }, {
    "source": "images/background.jpg",
    "gallery": ["images/house-name-1.jpg", "images/house-name-2.jpg", "images/house-name-3.jpg"],
    "short_desc": "3 BR, 2 Bath, West Orange, NJ",
    "long_desc": "Single Family Home for sale by owner in West Orange, NJ. Charming colonial in great location on large park-like property in West Orange, border of Roseland. Living room with beamed ceiling and wood stove, eat-in kitchen with granite countertops. Updated bath, oversized laundry room off kitchen also serves as pantry. Spiral staircase leads to 3 bedrooms on second floor. Three-season sunroom leads to deck and beautiful backyard, great for entertaining. Fenced front and side yard, with koi pond. Newer roof, freshly painted exterior.",
    "address": "55 Laurel Ave West Orange, NJ 07052",
    "sq_ft": "1,618 sqft",
    "price": "344,900",
    "tags": ["For Purchase", "Single-family"]
  }, {
    "source": "images/background.jpg",
    "gallery": ["images/house-name-1.jpg", "images/house-name-2.jpg", "images/house-name-3.jpg"],
    "short_desc": "3 BR, 2 Bath, Berkely Heights, NJ",
    "long_desc": "Great 2 family in a prime location. Close to public transportation, schools, and shopping.",
    "address": "268 Washington Ave Belleville, NJ 07109",
    "sq_ft": "3,456 sqft",
    "price": "140,000",
    "tags": ["For Purchase", "Multi-family", "Duplex", "House"]
  }, {
    "source": "images/background.jpg",
    "gallery": ["images/house-name-1.jpg", "images/house-name-2.jpg", "images/house-name-3.jpg"],
    "short_desc": "1 BR Studio, Newark, NJ",
    "long_desc": "Great 2 family in a prime location. Close to public transportation, schools, and shopping.",
    "address": "268 Washington Ave Belleville, NJ 07109",
    "sq_ft": "3,456 sqft",
    "price": "140,000",
    "tags": ["For Purchase", "Single-family", "2 Car Garage", "House"]
  }, ]
}

// Set variable for houses in images object
var home = houses.house;

// create house card for each house in houses object
$.each(home, function(index, value) {


  var new_tag = home[index].tags;

  $.each(new_tag, function(key, value) {
    $(".homes-tags").append("<p class='tag'>" + value + "</p>");
  });


  $('#homes-list').append('<div class="house-card"><div class="row"><div class="col span_7"><h2 class="short-desc">' + value.short_desc + '</h2><p class="address">' + value.address + '</p><p class="sqft">' + value.sq_ft + '</p><p class="price">' + value.price + '</p><p class="long-desc">' + value.long_desc + '</p></div><div class="col span_5 image"><img src="' + value.source + '" width="100%" /><p class="homes-tags"></p></div></div><div class="clear"></div></div>');

});
```

Please see jsfiddle for code issue
https://jsfiddle.net/vtc1ewrz/

Comment: What does _display correctly_ mean? What's your expected result?

Comment: @rac They don't correspond with the object data they are associated with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a bit messy, you're approaching this from the wrong angle. But the true problem is that you're applying the tags to an element that hasn't been added to the page yet. And then you repeat the process, so you're basically replacing `.homes-tags` on every new house you're iterating over.

I've changed the code to the following, thus solving your problem:

```
// create house card for each house in houses object
$.each(home, function(index, value) {
  var new_tag = home[index].tags;

  var newHtml = '<div class="house-card"><div class="row"><div class="col span_7"><h2 class="short-desc">' + value.short_desc + '</h2><p class="address">' + value.address + '</p><p class="sqft">' + value.sq_ft + '</p><p class="price">' + value.price + '</p><p class="long-desc">' + value.long_desc + '</p></div><div class="col span_5 image"><img src="' + value.source + '" width="100%" /><div class="homes-tags">';

  $.each(new_tag, function(key, value) {
    newHtml += '<p class="tag">' + value + '</p>';
  });

  newHtml += '</div></div></div><div class="clear"></div></div>';

  $('#homes-list').append(newHtml);
});
```

However, to be honest, this isn't great in general. You're mixing logic with presentation, for example. Also, `$.each` is more *‘expensive’* than simply using a `for` loop.

Comment: thank you for the help. Would you please elaborate on mixing logic with presentation? I come at development from design so now that I am knowledgable on how to write jquery I am trying to figure out how to do it cleaner, thank you for the help and the knowledge!

Comment: That's a big discussion in itself, but I suggest you look into templating languages. jQuery in particular has many options to do just that. The problem with your code is that you're attaching HTML to the page with jQuery, and that HTML is defined in your script. That's mixing logic (JS) with presentation (HTML).